# How to get a file out of a failed build-pod from OpenShift?

Tags: cloud, kubernetes, containers, openshift-online-3

I have a buildconfig on OpenShift which fails to build. The output tells me that the `server.log` file might contain more info. But OpenShift is deleting the build-pod immediately after the run, so I can't access the file.

I'm not quite familar with OpenShift, but there does not seem to be a command to start a pod/container. In the buildConfigs Yaml, there is also nothing that looks like it does the trick. Adding a restartPolicy did not help.

How to get the files contents?

edit1: The postCommit hook of the buildConfig does not run. I set it to

```
postCommit:
  script: echo POSTCOMMIT-HOOK && cat /home/payara/paasDomain/logs/server.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to keep your container running inside a build-pod by introducing an artificial never ending task inside it:

```
postCommit:
  command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--"]
  args: ["while true; do sleep 60; done;"]
```

then just exec to the container inside a pod to analyze internal server.log file with:

```
kubectl exec pod <pod_name> -c <container_name> -- /bin/bash
```

I hope it will help you.
Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-container-running-on-kubernetes) also for other methods to keep pod running in Kubernetes.

Comment: The postCommit hook is not running in my case, I guess it has to do with the image I'm using of which I have no choice (it's a company-internal image). Your link is interesting though. Thanks for that.